# Abstraction vs. performance when working with arrays

Tags: c++, performance, abstraction

This is a question about a concern I have about choosing between better performance and clearer code (better abstraction) when dealing with arrays. I tried to distill it down to a toy example.

C++ is particularly good at allowing abstractions without hurting performance. The question is whether this is possible in examples similar to the one below.

Consider a trivial arbitrary-size matrix class that uses contiguous row-major storage:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

class Matrix {
    int nrow, ncol;
    double *data;
public:
    Matrix(int nrow, int ncol) : nrow(nrow), ncol(ncol), data(new double[nrow*ncol]) { }
    ~Matrix() { delete [] data; }

    int rows() const { return nrow; }
    int cols() const { return ncol; }

    double & operator [] (int i) { return data[i]; }

    double & operator () (int i, int j) { return data[i*ncol + j]; }
};
```

It has a 2D indexing `operator ()` to make it easy to work with.  It also has `operator []` for contiguous access, but a better-abstracted matrix may not have this.

Let's implement a function that takes an n-by-2 matrix, essentially a list of 2D vectors, and normalizes each vector in-place.

The clear way:

```
inline double veclen(double x, double y) {
    return std::sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

void normalize(Matrix &mat) {
    assert(mat.cols() == 2); // some kind of check for correct input
    for (int i=0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
        double norm = veclen(mat(i,0), mat(i,1));
        mat(i,0) /= norm;
        mat(i,1) /= norm;
    }
}
```

The fast, but less clear way:

```
void normalize2(Matrix &mat) {
    assert(mat.cols() == 2);
    for (int i=0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
        double norm = veclen(mat[2*i], mat[2*i+1]);
        mat[2*i] /= norm;
        mat[2*i+1] /= norm;
    }
}
```

The second version (`normalize2`) has the potential to be faster because it is written in a way that it is clear that the second iteration of the loop will not access data that was computed in the first iteration.  Thus it can potentially make better use of SIMD instructions.  [Looking at godbolt, this seems to be what happens](https://godbolt.org/g/sMiUHA) (unless I'm misreading the assembly).

In the first version (`normalize`), the compiler can't know that the input matrix is not n-by-1, which would lead to overlapping array accesses.

**Question:** Is it possible to somehow tell the compiler that the input matrix is really n-by-2 in `normalize()` to allow it to optimize to the same level as it does in `normalize2()`?

---

Addressing the comments:

- John Zwinck: I went and did the benchmark. `normalize2()` is considerably faster (2.4 vs 1.3 seconds), but *only if* I remove the `assert` macros or if I define `NDEBUG`.  That is a rather counterintuitive effect of `-DNDEBUG`, isn't it?  It reduces performance instead of improving it.
- Max: Evidence is both the godbolt output I linked to and the above benchmark. I am also interested in the case when these two functions cannot be inlined (e.g. because they are in a separate translation unit).
- Jarod42 and bolov: This is the answer I was looking for. Confirmed by the benchmark mentioned in the first point.  Still, this is important to know in case one implements one's own `assert` (which is exactly what I do in my application).

Comment: Which one is actually faster when you run it for realistic inputs?

Comment: Gonna need some evidence for "the compiler can't know that the input matrix is not n-by-1." I would expect the compiler to be smart enough to inline both method calls, making your two examples identical.

Comment: if your `assert` uses something similar to `__assume()` / `__builtin_unreachable`, code could generates same assembly.

Comment: `if (mat.cols() != 2) __builtin_unreachable (void);`

Comment: expression template linear algebra libraries approach the general problem by having compile-time variants of each function, whenever it makes sense; for example, `mat.topRows<2>(i,0)` would internally assume a compile time  ncol == 2, making the assert() consequences explicit

Comment: Just a side note: you can use [std::hypot](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) instead of `veclen()`

Comment: @JohnZwinck Please see update.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @bolov Same comment as above, I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Germán Thanks!  I knew that, but when I used it, the compiler generated a function call (even with `-ffast-math`). With `veclen` it didn't, so it was clearer how the calculation was done.

Comment: FYI I benchmarked this on a matrix with a hundred million rows and the "fast" way was faster by less than a _hundredth_ of a second: 1.372 seconds vs 1.363. So yes it is an optimization, but not a big one.

Comment: @Max That happens to be the figure I get too with `300000000` rows on my machine, i.e. 1.3 seconds, but only if I use `assert`. If I remove it, or if I define `-DNDEBUG`, then the timing jumps to 2.4 s.  I put the normalize functions into a separate translation unit to prevent inlining.  I haven't tried the inline version *without assert* yet.

Comment: @Max [Here's a quick-and-dirty benchmark](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d62k1akj8ycz904/norm-bench.zip?dl=0), compiled with clang 5.0, `-ffast-math -O3 -std=c++14`.  Adding `-DNDEBUG` slows `normalize` down, but not `normalize2`.

Comment: If you're OK with sacrificing a bit of accuracy, you can use a reciprocal square root and multiply by that. Without AVX512 the reciprocal square root would have to be done on a float though, so the extra time from the conversions may kill that idea. Either way, add `-march=native`.

Comment: @Germán I found `hypot` to be *much* slower than `veclen` when compiling with gcc. With clang they perform about the same.  Strange.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it can be explained because of the algorithm as a whole is more precise. Quote from doc: “Computes the square root of the sum of the squares of x and y, **without undue overflow or underflow at intermediate stages of the computation**”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer that is acceptable to me was essentially given by @bolov and @Jared42 in the comments. Since they did not post it, I will do so myself.

To let the compiler know that the matrix is of size n-by-2, it is sufficient to add code to the beginning of the function that makes the rest of the code unreachable when the matrix size is not correct.

For example, adding

```
if (mat.cols() != 2)
    throw std::runtime_error("Input array is not of expected shape.");
```

to the beginning of `normalize()` allows it to run exactly as fast as `normalize2()` (1.3 instead of 2.4 seconds in my benchmark with clang 5.0).

We can also add an `assert(mat.cols() == 2)`, but this results in the counterintuitive effect that defining `-DNDEBUG` during compilation makes the function considerably slower (as it removes the assertion).

Answer (score 1):

I believe templates let you achieve both performance and readability.

By templating the size of your matrix (like popular math libraries do), you let the compiler know at compile time a lot of info.

I modified a bit your little class:

```
template<int R, int C>
class Matrix {
    double data[R * C] = {0.0};
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    int rows() const { return R; }
    int cols() const { return C; }
    int size() const { return R*C; }

    double & operator [] (int i) { return data[i]; }

    double & operator () (int row, int col) { return data[row*C + col]; }
};

inline double veclen(double x, double y) {
    return std::sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

template<int R>
void normalize(Matrix<R, 2> &mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        double norm = veclen(mat(i, 0), mat(i, 1));
        mat(i, 0) /= norm;
        mat(i, 1) /= norm;
    }
}

template<int R>
void normalize2(Matrix<R, 2> &mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        double norm = veclen(mat[2 * i], mat[2 * i + 1]);
        mat[2 * i] /= norm;
        mat[2 * i + 1] /= norm;
    }
}
```

I also prefer to put data as plain member (=without pointer), so you can choose during the matrix construction where the memory is (stack or heap).

The nice extra is you are now sure at compile time that the normalize functions only accept n-by-2 matrix.

I didn't test my code on compiler explorer, because honestly I can't decipher asm. So, yes, I claim my version to be better without being sure ;)

A last word: don't roll your own matrix, use a library, like glm or eigen.

A last word²: If you don't know what to choose, prefer readability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was aware of this, but in some applications it may be necessary to use an arbirtrary-size matrix class.  In my application the data is coming from a C library (actually from a higher-level language), and it may have any dimensions. I would put in a check to verify that it is indeed n-by-2 and abort with an error otherwise.  After this, the function could still use a special (templated) n-by-2 matrix class to wrap the raw data, and do calculations with it. It is indeed a possible solution (so +1), but it feels a bit cumbersome due to the use of two kinds of ...

Comment: ... data structures: one to receive the input (in the format of the C library), and check the size; another one to do the calculation with a known column count.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments, because they were wrong and badly formatted ;) I have more understanding of your problem now ! Can you show us how you expect to convert the data coming from the C library to your Matrix implementation ?

Comment: The Matrix's `data` pointer would be simply set to point to that data (it's in the same format, and the Matrix serves primarily for indexing and for storing the dimensions).

Comment: I'm not sure it answers your question anymore, but I did some code that might help you. I made a flexible template - based Matrix class, that can accept an arbitrary number of rows, and each row as a type known at compilation (so the compiler can optimize what he has to). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ddc5838d53081fd